# How to push to an array using index.of and if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm trying to figure out how to push an additional value to an array if my index.Of is equal or greater than 0. However the below code doesn't seem to work, I don't get any errors and I've checked the index.0f and it always equals 0.

```
var groups = ['a,b,c,']

function myfunction () {
    
    if (groups.indexOf('a,b,c,') >= 0) {
       groups.push('d') 
    }
}

console.log(groups);
```

Comment: Invoke `myfunction()` and then check the result of `groups`

Comment: Thanks man! I've been learning JS myself over the last few days during lockdown and keep making stupid mistakes. Now works!

Answer (score 0):

Just call your `myFunction()`. Also, you can use `incldes` method, and declare your array as a `const`:

```
const groups = ['a,b,c,'];

function myfunction() {
    if (groups.includes('a,b,c,')) {
       groups.push('d') 
    }
}

myfunction();
console.log(groups);
```